# Generate a custom Google Cardboard QR Code without google configurator (because its broken)

Tags: google-cardboard

I would like to generate a QR code for a Google Cardboard that did not have one. Usually you would use https://wwgc.firebaseapp.com/ for this, but it doesn't work anymore.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This site works, generates a QR code, you just need to enter the correct data. Accepts these QR code Cardboard https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo
You can find out the data of the glasses "VR Calibration for Cardboard" (VR glasses setting) The site is in Russian. https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=737005&st=100 If it does not download from the site, register. https://4pda.to/forum/dl/post/8460742/VrCalibration_20160721_1.2_gazePointerFix.apk Developer: AnRael Homepage: http://anrael.com Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anrael.vrcc

Comment: seems sketchy, tbh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34288954)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (2024-03-12):** I no longer seem find any of the alternative websites hosting the viewer profile generator mentioned in the original answer. The original answer is left in case you manage to find such a website, but an alternative method of generating the QR directly from the parameter values has also been added at the end.

### Original answer

There is another way I've found, but there are quite a few hoops to jump through.

https://wwgc.firebaseapp.com/ seems to be completely broken. Luckily there are alternative websites hosting the viewer profile generator which are, if not fully operational, at least partially working.

1. Find one of these alternative websites on a desktop computer by searching for the term `"Viewer Profile Generator Manufacturing a VR viewer?"` (with quotation marks) using DuckDuckGo (Google doesn't give me any results).
2. A QR-code is supposed to be generated. If it's missing, then open your browser's console (Ctrl+Shift+I in Firefox) and look for the entry:

```
Short URL error: {

  "error": {

    "code": 400,

    "message": "We could not match param '[website]/3d.html?u=[u_code]' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]",

    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

3. Write down the end of the URI in the error message (above denoted by `[u_code]` ).
4. Go to `https://wwgc.firebaseapp.com/3d.html?u=[u_code]` using Google Chrome on your Android device, while keeping the previous website open on your desktop computer.
5. A stereoscopic 3D rendering should be shown on your Android device.
6. Edit the parameters on your desktop computer to your liking while looking through your Google Cardboard.
7. Click on the button "Save or Store Viewer Parameters" above the parameter form (not the button at the bottom).
8. Copy the shown URI ( `http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=[p_code]` ).
9. Go to an online QR-code generator and paste this URI.
10. Open Google Cardboard on your Android device and scan the generated QR-code.

### Generate from values without an alternative website

While the website is broken, the underlying JavaScript functions can still be utilised.

1. Go to https://wwgc.firebaseapp.com/ .
2. Open your browser's console (Ctrl+Shift+I in Firefox).
3. Edit the parameters in the code below to ones corresponding to your VR headset:

```
// Generate a paramter object from a generic URI
params = CARDBOARD.uriToParamsProto("http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=CgtWZW5kb3IgbmFtZRIKTW9kZWwgbmFtZR1g5VA9JY_CdT0qEAAASEIAAEhCAABIQgAASEJYATUpXA89OggK1yM8j8J1PlAAYAA");

// Edit the values of the paramter variable
params.vendor = "Vendor name";
params.model = "Model name";
params.primary_button = 0;
params.has_magnet = false;
params.vertical_alignment = 1;
params.inter_lens_distance = 0.060;
params.screen_to_lens_distance = 0.051;
params.tray_to_lens_distance = 0.035;
params.distortion_coefficients[0] = 0.01;
params.distortion_coefficients[1] = 0.24;
fov_angle = 50;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++) {params.left_eye_field_of_view_angles[i] = fov_angle;};

// Print the new URI to the console
console.log("http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=" + params.toBase64().replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, ''));
// Return 'params' for inspection in the console 
params
```

4. Copy the URI from the console output ( `http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=[p_code]` ).
5. Go to an online QR-code generator and paste this URI.
6. Open Google Cardboard on your Android device and scan the generated QR-code.

Comment: all give me 404

Comment: I've removed the links to the alternative viewer profile generators from my answer since they all give 404-errors also for me. If you click on the links from DuckDuckGo they work as intended, but not if you paste the URL in the browser's address bar or link from here. I have no idea why. Perhaps it has something to do with the Firebase Dynamic Link the webpages are using? Either way, I'm afraid you might have to go the long way round using a search engine.